# Should I write the name of states, cities in capitals for JavaScript code while it's naming conventions suggest camel case

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, naming-conventions

I'm a junior JS developer, and I'm not sure what's considered `best practice` for naming the variables that might be connected to the front-end interface.
For example, I'm trying to provide a `list of the states and their cities`; I was wondering if I should abide by the `JS naming conventions` for writing Object property names or write them in `CAPITALS.`
And also, should I put space between the multi-part names or better not?

sum up:

- naming object properties
- naming array element as a value of object property of an object
- naming the parent object itself
- in Capitals ?? with spaces ??

For example:

```
let states = {
    Alabama: ["Alexander City", "Andalusia", "Anniston", "Athens"],
    Alaska: ["Anchorage", "Cordova"],
    Arizona: ["Lake Havasu City", "Window Rock"],
    Arkansas: ["Arkadelphia", "Benton"],
    California: ["Costa Mesa", "Mountain View"],
};
```

Comment: The important part is to be consistent.

Comment: Depends on ... If the names are used as data too, then name the names as they should show up. Notice that when there are spaces in the property names, you've to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation) to access a property, and when initializing the object, the keys must be wrapped with quotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, naming recommendation questions are off-topic because they are opinion-based. See the [help] for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**camelCasing** is generally used as a best practice for naming variables and sometimes object keys; however, object keys can be **snake_cased** or have the **First letter be capital** and still be following best practices.

The array values are fine and should stay as is.